# CucumberJS Console Output Given,When,Then Test Steps during run time

Tags: javascript, protractor, bdd, cucumberjs

Using [protractor-cucumber-framework](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-cucumber-framework)

How do I modify the console output of the CucumberJs that will output the steps during run time.

Example Scenario in Feature:

```
Given that Home Page is Displayed
When I Click Sales Button at Home Page
Then Sales Page is Displayed
```

When Running the Test, it should output the ff. in the console.

```
Given that Home Page is Displayed - Passed
When I Click Sales Button at Home Page - Passed
Then Sales Page is Displayed - Passed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change protractor conf.js to specify a formatter in `cucumberOpts` as following:

```
exports.config = {

    cucumberOpts: {
        format: [require.resolve('cucumber-pretty')]
    }}
}
```

Comment: To add to this https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#formats are all the available formats

Comment: Produce an error:

Error: Cannot find module 'cucumber-pretty'

in my cucumberjs changelog.md under node_modules

`pretty` formatter has been removed. All errors are now reported in a `pretty` format instead. The `progress` formatter is now the default.

State on the cucumberjs Update
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2017-08-08


 Is there another way to print steps other than using pretty?

Comment: You need add `cucumber-pretty` as dependency in package.json. And install it before your trying.

Comment: This is my cucumberOptions format: [
    'node_modules/cucumber-pretty',
    `json:${config.jsonReports}/report.json`,
    './built/e2e/support/allure-reporter.js',
  ], and still I did not get this in the Jenkins console output